# gradle kotlin dsl - How to configure dependencies for subprojects

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm creating gradle multi project for kotlin programming.

When I create `dependencies`  under `subprojects` in main project `build.gradle.kts` I'm getting error **Configuration with name 'implementation' not found**.

Below is my configuration -

```
    plugins {
        kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.61" apply false
    }

    subprojects {   
        dependencies {
            val implementation by configurations
            implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
        }
    }
```

Once I move the plugins and dependencies into subproject build.gradle.kts then it is working fine.
How can I make dependencies under `subprojects` work fine?

Code is on [github](https://github.com/rajcspsg/mastering-kotlin/blob/gradle-subproject-implementation-error/build.gradle.kts).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

With Kotlin dsl, you can add your dependencies as long as you use either `apply(plugin = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")` or `apply(plugin = "java")`.

Those needs to be where you put your `dependencies { .. }`, usually inside a `subprojects { .. }`.

So here would be a simple b*uild.gradle.kts* that would propagate the kotlin dependency in all its subprojects.

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.50"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

subprojects {
   apply(plugin = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")

   dependencies {
      implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
   } 

   tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
       kotlinOptions {
           freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
           jvmTarget = "11"
       }
   }

}
```

(You would still need to have the kotlin plugin, however no need to specify the version in the other subproject once defined at the root)

Comment: A simple question I'm hoping you can answer - why do we need to reapply the kotlin plugin at the subprojects level even after applying it in the root project level with the plugins block?

Comment: It was at the time a limitation from the gradle [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html?_ga=2.52221289.1756720240.1610986438-823552276.1554568232#type-safe-accessors). To apply the plugin to all projects you could try `allprojects{ kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.50" }`

Comment: this helped me after a few hours of trying to make it all running.. thanks @sylhare! however, I still can't put `implementation` without quotation marks because Gradle reports an error: "Unresolved reference: implementation"; to make it running I had to add `val implementation by configurations` before my `dependencies { }` declaration

Answer (score 4):

Adding the below configuration worked for me

```kotlin
  buildscript {
     repositories {
        maven {
        url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
        }
     }
     dependencies {
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.61")
     }
  }

  subprojects {
    apply(plugin = "java")
    apply(plugin = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")

    dependencies {
        val implementation by configurations
        implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
    }
  }
```

Comment: At least for me, it doesn't need `apply(plugin = "java")`

Answer (score 0):

In your root build.gradle.kts you can also exclude projects if you want:

```
subprojects {
    if (!project.name.contains("ios")) {
       apply("${rootDir}/ktlint.gradle.kts")
       apply(plugin = "org.jetbrains.kotlinx.kover")
       apply(plugin = "com.diffplug.spotless")
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the way to do it:

```
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.7.20"
}

allprojects {
    apply(plugin = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")
}
```

Comment: The question is about declaring dependencies in subprojects. `allprojects` is therefore too wide.