# How to set dependencies of all sub-projects in android+gradle multi-module project?

Tags: android, gradle

I want all submodules of a certain module to depend on another module `:core:log`

I did the following try:

first:

```kotlin
plugins {
  id("sage.android.library")
}

android {
  namespace = "com.sage.feature.work"
}

dependencies{
  subprojects{
      implementation(project(":core:log"))
  }
}
```

secend:

```kotlin
subprojects{
  dependencies{
    implementation(project(":core:log"))
  }
}
```

third:

```kotlin
dependencies{  
  subprojects{
    dependencies{
      implementation(project(":core:log"))
    }
  }
}
```

first not working, the second and third reported the error directly.

> org.gradle.api.artifacts.UnknownConfigurationException: Configuration with name 'implementation' not found.

What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There's a quick + dirty solution you're heading toward which I'll describe anyway because it's commonly done and still informative to know how it works. Then there's the recommended solution that's a little more involved.

#### 1. Quick + dirty

Your second example can be made to work (third just has redundant nesting that doesn't help). The issue is that when you're trying to add this dependency to all your sub-projects from here they don't yet have that "configuration" because the plugin to create it (java / kotlin / ...) hasn't yet been applied. So a quick fix is to add the plugin into that subprojects block first, something like this:

```
subprojects {
    apply(plugin = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")
    
    implementation(project(":core:log"))
}
```

This way you'll apply that plugin from here, it will create the configuration, and then you can add the dependency to it. You can find examples of this in other answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61621769/55488).

What's wrong with this? The tight-coupling issues (a bit like class inheritance). [Gradle docs advise against this](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/sharing_build_logic_between_subprojects.html#sec:convention_plugins_vs_cross_configuration) and you can find an explanation there as to why:

> looking at the subproject’s build script ... harder to understand the logic of a particular subproject ... grows complex with more and more conditional logic and a higher maintenance burden ... can also introduce configuration-time coupling ... which can prevent optimizations like configuration-on-demand from working properly

#### 2. Recommended approach

Also mentioned in that same page is the approach they do advise: [Convention plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/sharing_build_logic_between_subprojects.html#sec:convention_plugins). You define a Gradle plugin in `buildSrc` that applies your conventions, then apply that plugin in your module. eg. you might have a "feature module" plugin, that applies the kotlin plugin, sets some compile options, adds some common dependencies, etc.

This way you're explicitly referencing the things you're adding into your subproject, rather than injecting them from outside. You're avoiding creating that tight and not-very-visible coupling to the root module. Instead you're favoring a compositional approach, where looking at the sub-project build file you can see everything that is included, and the order in which things will get configured is more obvious (so you don't get weird surprises like this one). More details and a sample project are also provided [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_convention_plugins.html).